# Is there an item similar to Excel spreadsheet in C#?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to add an item in C# project that is similar to Excel spreadsheet? I need to add a report for my tests that would have TestName, TestStatus, Time, etc in each column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a datatable is what you're looking for, my friend. ;)

The datagridview is also a useful tool is you want to display datatables and whatnot.

You can find it in the toolbox. =) Hope this helps.

Additionally, this website might give you some more information as to what you want with some examples:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable

Answer (score 0):

If you're using asp with c#, a gridview is a good choice in my opinion.